# where clicking on a label checks other check box

Tags: html, reactjs, input, label

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTwnn.gif)

There is a problem that only the top one is selected no matter which item I press.

When I take out the htmlFor of the label, it works without a problem. There is also a way to wrap the input with a label, but I can't because of the css.

```
{list
        .filter((el) => {
          if (activeMenu === "All") {
            return true;
          } else if (activeMenu === "Doing") {
            return el.done === false;
          } else {
            return el.done === true;
          }
        })
        ?.map((item, i) => (
          <div className="todo-li" key={uuidv4()}>
            <input
              id="todo"
              name="checkbox"
              className="todo-checkbox"
              type="checkbox"
              checked={item.done}
              onChange={() => onClickCheck(item)}
            />
            <label htmlFor="todo" className="todo-item">
              {item.name}
            </label>
            <button
              id={item.id}
              className="delete-button"
              onClick={() => onClickDelete(item.id)}
            >
              <FaTrashAlt />
            </button>
          </div>
        ))}
```

Comment: Instead htmlFor use actual for attibute

Comment: You are passing same id for all the input elements. Change your id and make it unique. May be use `id` of todo if you have one. Something like `id={`todo-${item.id}`}` this.

Answer (score 0):

Do this..

```
          {list
          .filter((el) => {
            if (activeMenu === "All") {
              return true;
            } else if (activeMenu === "Doing") {
              return el.done === false;
            } else {
              return el.done === true;
            }
          })
          ?.map((item, i) => (
            <div className="todo-li" key={uuidv4()}>
              <input
                id={`todo${item.id}`}
                name="checkbox"
                className="todo-checkbox"
                      type="checkbox"
                checked={item.done}
                onChange={() => onClickCheck(item)}
              />
              <label htmlFor={`todo${item.id}`} className="todo-item">
                {item.name}
              </label>
                    <button
                id={item.id}
                className="delete-button"
                onClick={() => onClickDelete(item.id)}
              >
                <FaTrashAlt />
              </button>
            </div>
          ))}
```